# Python zipfile try except not passing over "zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back"

Tags: python, error-handling, unzip, try-except, python-zipfile

I am working on a python script to unzip a folder of nested zip files. In general, it seems to be working, but when it comes to one of the files I always receive this error:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

I initially tried using a `try` and `except` to pass over this, but that didn't work. I then tried adding into the except clause `except zipfile.BadZipFile` after reading various posts on here regarding it, but I still am receiving the same error. Here is how my code looks:

```
import os
import zipfile
folder_path = [MY FOLDER PATH HERE]

def extract_zip(filepath_in, filepath_out, password):
    if is_zip(filepath_in):
        print(filepath_in)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath_in, 'r') as zip_file:
            zip_file.extractall(filepath_out, pwd = bytes(password, 'utf-8'))

error_list = []
zip_count = 1           
while zip_count > 0:   
    filelist = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):      
        for file in files:
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file)) 
       
    zip_count = 0   
    for name in filelist:
        if name[(len(name) - 4):(len(name))] == ".zip":      #if file name ends in .zip
            zip_count =+ 1
            try:    
                extract_zip(name, name[0:(len(name) - 4)] , password)
                os.remove(name)    
            except zipfile.BadZipFile as fail:
                error_list.append(name), fail
                pass
```

I am unsure of how else to either have the error ignored or if there is some other way to extract the file.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not coment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: in python you don't have to use `len(name)-4` but you can use directly `-4` like  `name[0:-4]` or even shorter `name[:-4]` and similar `name[-4:]` instead of `name[(len(name) - 4):(len(name))]` . But you don't need it  - use `if name.endswith(".zip")`. Eventuall use `glob.glob("*.zip")` instead of `os.walk()`

Comment: it can be error directly in C/C++ library `zlib` and maybe you can't catch it.